# Representing reciprocal relationships in Mongo DB

Tags: python, mongodb, nosql

I have a group of things (genes) in a mongoDB. I'm doing an analysis to see how similar each gene is to each other gene, and I'd like to store that information in the database. I currently have different documents in the database for each gene that contains information like what species the gene came from and the DNA sequence. Each one of course also has a unique identifier `_id`.

When I do the analysis, I will get back information on how similar genes are by percent (their `perc_identity`). Typically, the lower bound that the analysis can return is ~70%, so there will not necessarily be a number for each gene, but each relationship is reciprocal (eg if `perc_identity(A:B) == 90` then `perc_identity(B:A) == 90`).

My question is what's the best data model to store these relationships so that I can retrieve them for further analysis? In other words, sometimes I'll want to grab all the pairs where `perc_identity > 95`. Other times I'll want to get all of the matches for a a particular gene. If it matters, the initial analysis to get `perc_identity` only needs to be done once and takes quite a long time already, so performance on the insert matters less than retrieval for later analysis.

Some ideas I had (I'm working with mongoDB in python if that matters):

1) Within the document for each gene, have a sub-document that contains all of the matched `_id`s and their `perc_identity`. Eg:

```
{
    _id: geneA,
    dna_seq: 'AACTG...',
    species: 'Homo sapiens',
    hits:{
        geneA: 100,
        geneB: 92,
        geneC: 70,
    }
},
{
    _id: geneB,
    dna_seq: 'AATTG...',
    species: 'Pan troglodytes',
    hits:{
        geneA: 92,
        geneB: 100,
    }
},
{
    _id: geneC,
    dna_seq: 'ATGGC...',
    species: 'Homo erectus',
    hits:{
        geneA: 70
        geneC: 100
    }
}
```

This will obviously cause some duplication of data, but this is the closest to how the data is spit out of the initial analysis. Most of the time, I won't care about most of the other data in the `gene` document, so I'm not clear if it will slow things down to have the information nested within them. I'm also not clear if there will be an efficient way to query for example, all `perc_identity > 90`. And every time I want to do an analysis, I'll retrieve double the amount of data that I need.

2) Have a separate document that just contains the gene `_id`s and all of its hits. Eg:

```
{
    _id: 'hits',
    geneA: {
        geneA: 100
        geneB: 92
        geneC: 70
    },
    geneB: {
        geneA: 92
        geneB: 100
    },
    # etc
}
```

This has the benefit that I don't have to mess with the gene documents at all. I could also have a different `hits` collection if that makes any difference. The other good thing is that there will be ~50k gene records, but only about 1-2% of them will have any hits at all, so the queries won't have to bother checking the majority of documents. Otherwise, this seems very similar to (1) to me.

3) Some way to have no redundancy. I can't think of good ways to do this. The bad way I thought of is to have the `perc_identity` be the key, and then have a list of `_id` tuples. I can round to the nearest integer percent. It seems like this would require checking for the presence of the `_id` in every tuple within a certain `perc_identity` every time I insert something, or inserting everything and then collapsing the set afterwards. And in this case, retrieving all matches to a particular `_id` seems like it would be horribly inefficient.

Or, since the order doesn't matter something like:

```
{
    _id: ?
    type: 'hit'
    pair1: geneA
    pair2: geneB
    perc_identity: 92
},
{
    _id: ??
    type:'hit'
    pair1: geneC
    pair2: geneA
    perc_identity: 70
},
# etc
```

---

Any critique on one of these strategies, or suggestions for other ways to represent this would be greatly appreciated. Let me know if there's other info I should provide or if I can clarify anything. If (1) or (2) seem like good strategies, I guess my only question is the best way to construct a query based on some `perc_identity` threshold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is never an easy question to answer! However, the guiding principle should be to decide based on the way you intend to use your data. In this case, you've mentioned two queries:

1. Grab all the pairs with `perc_identity > 95`
2. Get all the matches for one gene

(Of course, there may be other common analyses that you plan to make--it would help to spell them out.)

Based on this, I would encourage you to go for a denormalized approach like the one you discuss in your third alternative. It does have some downsides, mainly on insert, which you seem to be aware of, but it makes the first type of query very easy:

```
db.hits.find({perc_identity: {$gt: 95}})
```

...whereas with any other approach you would need to iterate over all the keys in other documents. For instance, with your first approach, you would need to retrieve the `hits` subdocuments for every gene, iterate over the keys of those subdocuments, and add to your list those that are greater than 95. This would need to be done out of mongodb/pymongo.

The other query is more complicated than with approaches 1 and 2, but not by much:

```
db.hits.find({$or: [{pair1: <your gene>}, {pair2: <your gene>}]})
```

So at the cost of some more logic on inserts, the two querying cases you mention become extremely simple and can be handled easily by the database server itself. If you have other common use cases that would be difficult to achieve with your third approach, then it would be worth revisiting it--but as it stands, that's what I would choose.

Two notes: first, the documentation of MongoDB has [some good advice on data modeling](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/data-modeling-introduction/) that may be worth reading. Second, as much as I like MongoDB, given what little I know about your problem domain this may be one case where a relational database might be a better fit.

Comment: Damn, I was hoping there was some magic I didn't know about. Can you say a little more about a relational database? I think of them like a 2d array, so I'd end up with the same problem (having to check rows and columns on insert or duplicating data)

Comment: @kevbonham ah yes, that is true, for the two queries mentioned, as well as for the insert issues, there is no real difference between mongo and relational databases. It matters a bit more, for example, if you want to find the species names of all matches with `<your gene>`--you either need to copy the name on insert of every entry in `hits`, which is clunky but not awful (the names likely won't change, so there's little harm) or do a lookup after you extract the matches.

Comment: In general, my gut instinct is that if I'm going to need to denormalize for the basic scenario anyway, I should consider relational. On the other hand, I've used MongoDB in scenarios where it is barely justified, and really everything turns out alright :-).